# Get the value of checkbox using ref in React

Tags: reactjs

is there any way to get value of checkbox using ref in React. Normal way return always value "on" to me.

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
    save: function(){
        console.log(this.refs.check_me.value);
    },

    render: function(){
        return <div><h1>MyForm</h1>
            <div className="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="check_me" /> Check me out
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For checkbox, use "checked" instead of "value":

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
  save: function () {
    console.log(this.refs.check_me.checked);
  },

  render: function () {
    return <div><h1>MyForm</h1>
      <div className="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ref="check_me" /> Check me out
        </label>
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  }
});
```

As a result:

[image]

Comment: Returns always undefined :-(

Comment: That's strange it works for me. I added a picture in my post if it can help

Comment: I'm very sorry @Damien Leroux I made a mistake when I copy your source code. Your code is valid. Thanks a lot. I works!

Answer (score 16):

There is a classic way to catch the event and corresponding values with the help of:

```
event.target.checked, event.target.name
```

You can see an example:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    onChangeFavorite(event){
        console.log(event.target.checked, event.target.name);
    };
    render(){
        return (<div><h1>MyForm</h1>
            <div className="checkbox">
                <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox1" 
                     onChange={this.onChangeFavorite} 
                     defaultChecked={false} /> 
                   Check me out
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
        </div>)
    };
};
```

Answer (score 11):

You can make the checkbox a controlled element by listening to `onChange` and giving it a `state` value. Try the following:

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
  save: function(){
    console.log(this.refs.check_me.value);
  },

  toggleCheckboxValue: () => {
    this.setState({checkBoxValue: !this.state.checkboxValue});
  },

  render: function(){
    return <div><h1>MyForm</h1>
        <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ref="check_me" value={this.state.checkboxValue} onChange={this.toggleCheckboxValue} /> Check me out
            </label>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  }
});
```

whenever the checkbox is clicked it will run the `toggleCheckboxValue` function, which will toggle the value of `this.state.checkboxValue`.

Just don't forget to initialize the `this.state.checkboxValue` function in your code.

**Note:** As ivarni pointed out, you may want to control the `checked` value specifically for checkboxes rather than `value`. Though both solutions will work.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's a perfectly valid, functional implementation of a controlled input element.

Comment: I don't know. The answer is fine.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote as the answer does provide a solution, but I personally feel it's abusing what `value` should be used for. If you look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) you'll see that it says *The value attribute is used to define the value submitted by the checkbox. The checked attribute is used to indicate whether this item is selected*. I haven't tested how it would affect a screenreader but it wouldn't surprise me if this confuses some poor blind person down the road.

Comment: @ivarni, well it's up to the programmer to give `value` an appropriate value instead of something that isn't. It's still perfectly valid to have a controlled checkbox.

Comment: I'm just saying that personally I would control the `checked` attribute and not the `value` for reasons I already outlined.

Comment: @ivarni, you're probably right. It makes more sense to do the `checked` rather than the `value`. I guess the above just demonstrates how to control a form element of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want it using `ref` specifically, but it can be done nativily:

```js
import React from 'react';

function CheckBox() {
  const [isSave, setIsSave] = React.useState(false);
  const handler = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    setIsSave(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={(ev) => handler(ev.target.checked)} />
      <label> Save me..</label>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CheckBox;
```