# Getting the value of checkbox in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to render components based on the checkbox selection. My approach was as follows:

```
class ReportMainCat extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
        this.report_next = this.report_next.bind(this);    
    };

    report_next() {    
        if(this.refs.sexual.checked) {
            return <PostOptionBar/>   
        }    
    }

    render() {            
        return (
            <div className="text_align_left">   
                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox"  ref="sexual"/>
                    <a>Sexual Content</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="selfharm"/>
                    <a>Threat or self harm</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="abuse"/>
                    <a>Abuse or bullying</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="illegal"/>
                    <a>Illegal substances</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="discrimination"/>
                    <a>Discrimination</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="copyright"/>
                    <a>Copyright or spam</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="nopermission"/>
                    <a>Humiliating, embarassing or posted without permission</a>
                </div>

                <button className="float_right" onClick={this.report_next}>Next</button>

                {this.report_next()}

            </div>        
        )    
    }
}
```

I'm checking if the checkbox is checked and rendering the component accordingly, but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

How do I fix this? Or is this the best approach to do what I want to do?

Comment: It looks like the ref object is not built before this line: {this.report_next()}

Comment: If so, how do i fix it?

Comment: follow this one man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833192/get-the-value-of-checkbox-using-ref-in-react

Answer (score 2):

It's advised not to use string refs in react components.

> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

So refs must be used in this manner

```
 ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
```

So your input tag should be something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ref={(input) => { this.sexualInput = input; }} />
```

And then in report_next() function you can get that value by using.

```
this.sexualInput.checked
```

Also do try to avoid using so many refs. Use state as much as possible in react components.

Answer (score 1):

[Suggestion As per DOC:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using
>   this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

**Changes:**

**1.** Returning a component on click of button will not do anything, for that you need to define a separate function just for onClick.

**2.** You need to use some `state` variable otherwise component will not re-rendered automatically and onclick of button you need to update that `state` value.

Check this snippet:

```js
class ReportMainCat extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           renderComponent: false
        }
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    };

    report_next(){
        if(this.refs.sexual && this.refs.sexual.checked){
            return <div> hello </div>
        }
    }
    
    buttonClick(){
       this.setState({
          renderComponent: true
       })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="text_align_left">

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox"  ref="sexual"/>
                    <a>Sexual Content</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="selfharm"/>
                    <a>Threat or self harm</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="abuse"/>
                    <a>Abuse or bullying</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="illegal"/>
                    <a>Illegal substances</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="discrimination"/>
                    <a>Discrimination</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="copyright"/>
                    <a>Copyright or spam</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="nopermission"/>
                    <a>Humiliating,embarassing or posted without permission</a>
                </div>

                <button className="float_right" onClick={this.buttonClick}>Next</button>

                {this.report_next()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReportMainCat/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SyntheticEvent, 'e'. Below is an example:

```
const element1 = "male";
const element2 = "female";

<input
 type="checkbox"
 name={element1}
 value={element1}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<label for="element" style={{ fontSize: 35 }}>
{element2}
 </label>

<input
 type="checkbox"
 name={element2}
 value={element2}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<label for="element" style={{ fontSize: 35 }}>
{element2}
 </label>




handleChange = (e) => {
// to find out if it's checked or not; returns true or false
const checked = e.target.checked;

// to get the checked value
const checkedValue = e.target.value;

// to get the checked name
const checkedName = e.target.name;

//then you can do with the value all you want to do with it.
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
class ReportMainCat extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           renderComponent: false
        }
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    };

    report_next(){
        if(this.refs.sexual && this.refs.sexual.checked){
            return <div> hello </div>
        }
    }
    
    buttonClick(){
       this.setState({
          renderComponent: true
       })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="text_align_left">

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox"  ref="sexual"/>
                    <a>Sexual Content</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="selfharm"/>
                    <a>Threat or self harm</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="abuse"/>
                    <a>Abuse or bullying</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="illegal"/>
                    <a>Illegal substances</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="discrimination"/>
                    <a>Discrimination</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="copyright"/>
                    <a>Copyright or spam</a>
                </div>

                <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" ref="nopermission"/>
                    <a>Humiliating,embarassing or posted without permission</a>
                </div>

                <button className="float_right" onClick={this.buttonClick}>Next</button>

                {this.report_next()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReportMainCat/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min`enter code here`.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Can you explain the solution ? Also note that `this.refs` [has issues](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

Comment: i am also searching for the answer