# How to pass checkbox state to onClick Function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently a bit lost with this - as I thought - trivial task. I have some checkboxes in my React App which have a onClick Function. Now I need to pass the info to the function, if I just checked or unchecked the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       name={field}
       id={field}
       onClick={() => this.buildTemplate(objectA, objectB, checkboxState)}
/>
<label htmlFor={field}>
    {getLabel(`${this.props.modelType}.${fieldName}`)} 
</label>
```

When the function is called, I need to do some stuff depending on the state of the checkbox.

```
buildTemplate = (objectA, objectB, checked) => {
    checked ? yep() : nope();
};
```

I tried to bind the checkbox like this, and it worked, but now I dont know how to pass the other arguments in this function.

```
onClick={this.testFunc.bind(this)}

...

testFunc(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked)
}
```

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833192/get-the-value-of-checkbox-using-ref-in-react?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), where the accepted answer suggested refs, but I may have a lot of checkboxes, and it seems a bit overkill to me, to create refs just to pass the current state of the checkbox. 
I think there is a dumb solution for this, but it seems like I can't figure it out.

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer and there is no need to change but I want to remember my answer as a newbie. I've edited it to explain why I preferred this method.

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for your answer and your time to be so detailed. I gave all the answers an upvote, since they are not wrong and can be absolutely helpful aswell. I just accepted the guy who posted the first helpful answer here, that actually helped me solve my problem, which I think is fair :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass event object from onClick handler to action method as below:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       name={field}
       id={field}
       onClick={(event) => this.buildTemplate(objectA, objectB, event)}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Send arguments like this

```
 onClick={(event) => this.buildTemplate(objectA, objectB, event)
```

then in the fuction use this

```
event.target.checked
```

to get value of checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Without binding your function and without an arrow function in your onClick, you can define an external arrow function and set this for onClick:

```
// or name this function as buildTemplate and use for onClick below
handleCheck = ( event ) =>
    event.target.checked
        ? yep()
        : nope()


<input type="checkbox"
       name={field}
       id={field}
       onClick={this.handleCheck}
/>
<label htmlFor={field}>
    {getLabel(`${this.props.modelType}.${fieldName}`)} 
</label>
```

I know you need some objects but I think you can reach those inside your function. Why I am suggesting this method: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Answer (score 2):

Its simple to get the result of checkbox change in React

see example [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

or

**Simply**

```
 <input type="checkbox"
   name={field}
   id={field}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
   />    





  handleInputChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;

     this.setState({
     [name]: value
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the event object in the onClick handler. Just look at the code below:

```
<input type="checkbox"
   name={field}
   id={field}
   onClick={(event) => this.buildTemplate(objectA, objectB, event)}
/>
```

Now you can easily get the value of the checkbox by the code below:

```
event.target.checked
```