# How to only select one checkbox in a React Native Android app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox, react-native-component

I'm trying to set up my first Android app in React Native.

Now there's this card (react-native-component) with multiple checkboxes inside (see code below).

Every time I try to select only one checkbox, it somehow checks all of them.

I know it has something to do with multiple states, but I can't get it to work.

How can I only select one checkbox?

JavaScript file:

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, ListView, Text, View, Alert, Platform, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Card, CheckBox, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class AgendaItemVote extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { checked: false };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Card title="Titel Agendapunt">
                    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at sapien at tellus interdum finibus. Nunc sagittis tincidunt orci, non viverra ligula feugiat id. Phasellus eleifend massa neque, eu scelerisque enim feugiat ac.
                    </Text>

                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <CheckBox
                            title='Ja'
                            checked={this.state.checked}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({
                                checked: !this.state.checked
                            })}
                        />
                         <CheckBox
                            title='Nee'
                            checked={this.state.checked}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({
                                checked: !this.state.checked
                            })}
                        />
                         <CheckBox
                            title='Onthouding'
                            checked={this.state.checked}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({
                                checked: !this.state.checked
                            })}
                        />

                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Button
                            title="Indienen"
                        />
                    </View>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingTop: 40,
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    },
    paragraph: {
      margin: 24,
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#34495e',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a specific state for each control. there is a solution for you:

```
   export default class AgendaItemVote extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            options: [
                {
                    title: 'Ja',
                    checked: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Nee',
                    checked: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Onthouding',
                    checked: false
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Card title="Titel Agendapunt">
                    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Vivamus at sapien at tellus interdum finibus. Nunc
                        sagittis tincidunt orci, non viverra ligula feugiat id.
                        Phasellus eleifend massa neque, eu scelerisque enim
                        feugiat ac.
                    </Text>

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        {this.state.options.map(opt => (
                            <CheckBox
                                title={opt.title}
                                checked={opt.checked}
                                key={opt.title}
                                onClick={() => {
                                  opt.checked = !opt.checked;
                                  this.setState({
                                        options: [
                                            ...this.state.options
                                        ]
                                    })
                            ></CheckBox>)
                        )}
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Button title="Indienen" />
                    </View>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
    },
    paragraph: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#34495e'
    }
});
```

Comment: While this is right what I needed, When trying to use this code, it doesn't show any checkbox.

Comment: fixed it, try now

Comment: While the checkboxes show now, it's still impossible to check them. So when I tap the checkbox, nothing happens

Comment: Would be nice :D

Comment: I had to change your react native components to some divs https://repl.it/repls/StaticNeedyWebpages

Comment: Have you checked it?

Comment: I was out of town for a week, will check now.

Comment: Still the same problem, after clicking the checkbox, the checkbox won't check

Comment: Note that also your code has some errors in terms of brackets

Comment: Error in code structure

Comment: the missing tags has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, after resolving the issue I am writing my answer here.

Consider the example below - (with hooks)

```
const checkboxComponent = () => {

  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = React.useState([
   { label: 'Customer', value: 'customer', checked: false },
   { label: 'Merchant', value: 'merchant', checked: false },
   { label: 'None', value: 'none', checked: false },
 ])

 const checkboxHandler = (value, index) => {
   const newValue = checkboxValue.map((checkbox, i) => {
    if (i !== index)
      return {
        ...checkbox,
        checked: false,
      }
    if (i === index) {
      const item = {
        ...checkbox,
        checked: !checkbox.checked,
      }
      return item
    }
   return checkbox
 })
 setCheckboxValue(newValue)
 }    

return (
   <View>
    {checkboxValue.map((checkbox, i) => (
        <View style={styles.checkboxContainer} key={i}>
          <CheckBox
            value={checkbox.checked}
            onValueChange={(value) => checkboxHandler(value, i)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.label}>{checkbox.label}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}

   </View>
 )
}
export default checkboxComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here,

```
checked={this.state.checked}
```

When you set `checked` to `true`, every checkbox is getting checked as you are using this value to `this.state.checked` in every checkbox.

Remove the `checked` and `onPress` from all the `checkboxes` and if you want to get the value of checked `checkbox` then you can use [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

For your reference:: [Get the value of checkbox using ref in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833192/get-the-value-of-checkbox-using-ref-in-react)

Comment: While this helps me a little bit, when removing "checked" and "onPress", the checkboxes wont check on click

Comment: @Splekke refer the reference link for that issue.