# Getting checkbox value in react onchek

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

How to get check value in react when passing dynamic value in checkbook and get these value when checkbook is checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of checkbox using ref in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833192/get-the-value-of-checkbox-using-ref-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Hey from what I understand, you are asking about how to check the value of your checkbox ( true if it is checked, false otherwise).

You can have your checkbox value stored in your component state so that you can access it anywhere in your component, then call `setState()` whenever the `onChange` event is fired.

```
class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           checked: true
        };

    render() {
        return (
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onChange={checked => { this.setState({ checked }) }} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to pass value prop in checkbox and on change I get these value.